# Loop through List multi-threading to ping hostnames

Tags: java, multithreading, socket, status-monitoring

I am new to Multi-threading. I have had a go at writing some code that loops through an `ArrayList`, gets a hostname and then pings the hostname. If the hostname is not pingable it adds the hostname to a list returned by the method.

I am very new to multi-threading so I was just wondering if someone could give me a hand with improving this. For example I've heard that you can pass an `ArrayList` to `Runnable` but I can't find any good examples on how to do this yet.

Please note that I am using **Java 5**.

```
private ArrayList<String> pingNonReplicatingRegisters (
    Collection<RegisterReplicationSynchTime> nonReplicatingRegisters) throws IOException {

    final ArrayList<String> nonPingableRegisters = new ArrayList<String>();    

    int nThreads = 15;
    final ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);

    for(RegisterReplicationSynchTime nonReplicatingRegister : nonReplicatingRegisters){

        final String registerHostName = nonReplicatingRegister.getRegisterName();

        es.execute(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                boolean status = false;
                Socket socket = null;
                PingBean pngBean = new PingBean();

                try {   
                    SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(registerHostName, 139);
                    socket = new Socket();
                    socket.connect(socketAddress, 1000); //1secs
                    status = true;
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {

                }
                finally {
                    if (socket != null) {
                        try {
                            socket.close();
                        } catch (PortUnreachableException e) {
                            socket = null;
                            System.err.println("Got an " + e);
                        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            socket = null;
                            System.err.println("Got an " + e);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            socket = null;
                        }
                    }
               }// finally
               /* return status */
               if (!status) {
                   nonPingableRegisters.add(registerHostName);
               }
           } 
        });
   }// for
   try {
       es.shutdown();
       es.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       List<Runnable> pending = es.shutdownNow();

       if (!pending.isEmpty()) {
           System.err.println("Pending threads: " + pending);
       }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return nonPingableRegisters;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some great answers!

Comment: Any particular reason why Java 5?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the [`Callable<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) interface:

> A task that returns a result and may throw an exception. Implementors define a single method with no arguments called `call`.

Instead of having to pass around a thread-safe `Collection` to gather your non-pingable servers, you can call [`ExecutorService.invokeAll(Collection)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-) to get a `List<Future<T>>`, which you can then retrieve the results.

First, I'll suggest having an implementation of `Callable<T>`:

```
public class Ping implements Callable<String> {

    private final String hostname;

    public Ping(String hostname) {
        this.hostname = hostname;
    }

    public String call() {
        // ... try to ping server
        // assume the results are stored in a boolean
        return isPingable ? "" : hostname;
    }

}
```

And then you can construct your `Collection<Ping>` to submit to the `ExecutionService`:

```
List<Ping> pingTasks = new ArrayList<Ping>(nonReplicatingRegisters.size());
for (RegisterReplicationSynchTime nonReplicatingRegister : nonReplicatingRegisters) {
    pingTasks.add(new Ping(nonReplicatingRegister.getRegisterName()));
}
// or use invokeAll(Collection, long, TimeUnit) for an explicit timeout
List<Future<String>> taskResults = es.invokeAll(pingTasks);
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Future<String> taskResult : taskResults) {
    try {
        String output = taskResult.get();
        if (!output.isEmpty()) {
            results.add(output);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // handle accordingly
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // handle accordingly
    }
}
```